# C# Freebase.properties fileNotFound & what it does?

Tags: java, freebase

I am having problems searching a fix for this freebase.properties file. I looked for through google apis and freebase site and also tried googling for a fix. But I couldn't find any helpful tips, except for a post that has the same problem as me. There is no fix though so I hope here will be anyone here to shine some light :)

**EDIT: The problem i'm encountering now is regarding the file "freebase.properties". I do not have the file and tried searching for it but no results, its not provided on google apis too :/ . Am not sure what it does to the sample codes below.**

Below are the snippets of the codes from the examples in freebase google apis.

```
public class TopicSample {
      public static Properties properties = new Properties();
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          properties.load(new FileInputStream("freebase.properties"));
          HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
          HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();
          JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
          String topicId = "/en/bob_dylan";
          GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic" + topicId);
          url.put("key", properties.get("API_KEY"));
          HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
          HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
          JSONObject topic = (JSONObject)parser.parse(httpResponse.parseAsString());
          System.out.println(JsonPath.read(topic,"$.property['/type/object/name'].values[0].value").toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? What is the connection between your posted code and the title of your headline?

Comment: Can you edit and make your question more clear..?

Comment: you should take out your api key

Comment: Based on how it's used in that program, it's just a simple text file named `freebase.properties` with `API_KEY = YOUR_API_KEY`, and obviously replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with the real deal. You can read more about the Properties class and the format it expects [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29). Otherwise just take out the entire properties object and just use your actual API key in place of `properties.get("API_KEY")`.

Comment: @sbat thanks very much for that, I've oversee that! Should have taken the steps to look into the properties.get method first! Appreciated much!